# Cannot sort elements each row matrix in Maple

Tags: math-software, maple

I want to sort descending of my matrix each row with **maple**,
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1&2\\-3&0&5\\-1&-5&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

become

$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
2&0&-1\\5&0&-3\\0&-1&-5
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

I typing in maple :

```
restart:
with(linalg):
A := matrix(3, 3, [0, -1, 2, -3, 0, 5, -1, -5, 0]):
evalm(sort(A, `>`));
```

But the result same as $A$. How to sort descending each row of matrix $A$?

Answer (score 0):

As a question about Maple programming (rather than about mathematics) this question belongs on either [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com) or [www.mapleprimes.com](http://www.mapleprimes.com) .

I'm not sure which version of Maple you're using, but lowercase `matrix` is deprecated in favour of `Matrix` (available since Maple 6 released in the year 2000).

Here are two ways to get that, using `Matrix`,

```
restart:
A := Matrix(3, 3, [0, -1, 2, -3, 0, 5, -1, -5, 0]);

                 [ 0  -1   2]
                 [          ]
            A := [-3   0   5]
                 [          ]
                 [-1  -5   0]

<seq(sort(A[i,1..-1],`>`), i=1..3)>;

                [2   0  -1]
                [         ]
                [5   0  -3]
                [         ]
                [0  -1  -5]

Matrix(map(sort,convert(A,listlist),`>`));

                [2   0  -1]
                [         ]
                [5   0  -3]
                [         ]
                [0  -1  -5]
```

If you insist on using the deprecated `matrix` then you can use the second approach above.

```
restart;
A := matrix(3, 3, [0, -1, 2, -3, 0, 5, -1, -5, 0]);

                 [ 0  -1   2]
                 [          ]
            A := [-3   0   5]
                 [          ]
                 [-1  -5   0]

matrix(map(sort,convert(A,listlist),`>`));

                [2   0  -1]
                [         ]
                [5   0  -3]
                [         ]
                [0  -1  -5]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I use maple 18